# Avoid JOIN when request with sort on foreign key

Tags: spring-mvc, jpa, spring-boot

I'm developping a Spring REST Web Service and I have a table with a foreign key and the following entity :

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = "id")
public class Foo {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    @NotNull
    private FooBar fooBar;

    public static Foo fromFooBar(FooBar fooBar) {
        return builder()
                .fooBar(fooBar)
                .build();
    }
}
```

Here is my repo :

```
public interface FooRepository extends JpaRepository<Foo, Long>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Foo> {
}
```

My service :

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class FooService {

    @Autowired
    private FooRepository repository;

    public Page<Foo> findAll(Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable) {
        return repository.findAll(predicate, pageable);
    }
}
```

And my controller :

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/foo")
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class FooController {

    private final FooService service;

    @RequestMapping
    public Page<Foo> findAll(@QuerydslPredicate(root = Foo.class) Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable) {
        return service.findAll(predicate, pageable);
    }
}
```

When I request with a sort on the foreign key : `api/foo?sort=fooBar_id,ASC`, the database is requested with a `JOIN`:

```
select foo.id as id, foo.fooBar_id as fooBarId from foo left outer join fooBar on foo.fooBar_id=fooBar.id order by fooBar.id asc limit ?
```

Is there a way to avoid this `JOIN` ? And just sort on the foreign key ?

Comment: I dont use JPA, but my guess is, because the `fooBar id` is present in the `FooBar` object and which is mapped to `fooBar` table, hence it adds the join

Comment: Yes it's what I though too, but as `foobar_id` is a field of `foo` in database, I don't understand why a join is necessary.

Comment: That's how I guess the query generation is designed. But a one-one join on a FK shouldn't be expensive.

Comment: but what JPQL is issued ? And which JPA provider is used ?

Comment: @DN1 I use Hibernate and for the JPQL, is there different ones ? If yes, where can I find which one is issued ?

Comment: Hibernate has its HQL?

Comment: which JPQL is issued? How about you look in the LOG of your chosen JPA provider? But then this is what you get if you wrap basic persistence / querying in layers of extra baggage (like Spring, REST etc), so have to dig when a problem comes up